# I am getting circular reference exception while parsing data from entity objeci in JSON

Tags: asp.net, json

I have made MVC 4 project in which there is another mvc project which is working as a engine i.e. getting data from DAL. Problem is I am getting circular reference exception while parsing data from entity objeci in JSON. I have been using navigation properties